# all installation attempts error out

Tags: 16.04

please look on this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-31 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  aptitude
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ppa-purge
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 6 312 B of archives.
After this operation, 24,6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 ppa-purge all 0.2.8+bzr63 [6 312 B]
Fetched 6 312 B in 0s (39,1 kB/s)      
Selecting previously unselected package ppa-purge.
(Reading database ... 265550 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ppa-purge_0.2.8+bzr63_all.deb ...
Unpacking ppa-purge (0.2.8+bzr63) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up ppa-purge (0.2.8+bzr63) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I was try this two process reinstall but without effects after OS restart.